# Generate PDF files version 1.6 or 1.7 with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation

Is there a way to generate newer format PDFs in Javascript?

A bunch of really cool projects online all seem to be limited to PDF documents version 1.3 or 1.4 max, among them are:

[jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/)

[pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake)

[pdfkit](https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit)

Found this interesting project: [HummusJS](https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS), implementing PDF version 1.6, but the functional code is actually written in C++. Looking for a pure JavaScript solution. Thanks

Comment: You mean, any way to change the *reported version*? (Which comes down to hunting down where in all those source files it gets written out.) Or actually be able to use the new *features* – if any – for newer versions? That is a much harder task, but I'd guess it to be theoretically possible.

Comment: @usr2564301 Interested in features